# Superpowers of a 5-Dimensional Being

Tags: science-based, space, super-powers, spacetime-dimensions, dimensions

So, I have seen the superpowers of a **4-Dimensional Being** pop up a few times on this site. However, I will instead talk about the powers of a being with one extra dimension, making them a **5-Dimensional Being**.

Here is some context. My world is a multiverse that follows the **Brane Multiverse Theory**, where a 4-D space-time continuum is just a single "brane" in this 5-D Bulk. Same for countless other 4-D universes, though they will either be small "sheets of paper" or "bubbles" in this higher dimension. Big Bangs happen due to either the branes colliding, or them being formed when higher-dimensional stars collapse.

This 5-D Bulk is Anti-De Sitter in nature, thus infinite. These 5 dimensions are basically 4 Space and 1 Time Dimension.

I understand that potential superpowers 4-D beings might have in the eyes of 3-D beings is X-Ray Vision, looking like Eldritch Beings and all. But what would a 5-D being have in the eyes of 3-D being? Similar powers, or more?

I ask this because as far as I have seen, the powers of 5-D beings are either too vague (*the Ghosts from Interstellar*) or too wacky (*5-D Imps from DC*). I wonder this because I picture some humans who have ascended to this higher dimension through something like a Reissner Nördstrom Black Hole's Cauchy Horizon, and realise they might have more than just "4-D powers" when they project themselves to the lower world from the higher one.

Lastly, I have seen another guy's idea of 5-D beings experiencing "serendipitous moment" or something, but I doubt his multiverse fits to mine.

PS: *Actually, other than X-Ray Vision or looking like Eldritch beings, I did not actually see any other superpower for 4-D beings, as a matter of a fact. Some say they could phase through and take things from the inside of other's bodies, but I can't confirm it. If the 5-D beings have same powers as 4-D beings, then feel free to just use the same 4-D being powers for an answer. I need higher dimensional powers in general.*

Comment: Are you talking about "full" 4D universes (i.e. 4D + time ) or relativistic 3D+1 universes?

Comment: Relativistic. 3 Space, 1 Time. And 5-D here is one more space beyond all infinite space-time continuums.

Comment: Then this creature is the same 4D supercreatures that were already discussed. Those discution imply newtonian "non-dimentional" time. Multiversness would add some more properties (as seeing all results of coin toss at once) but that wouldn't be much. Are you sure you don't want some timetravel(timebending)? Or relativity is to be more of consern?

Comment: Actually, come to think about it, I did not see that many 4D power suggestions at all, rather than X-Ray Vision and looking weird. I think there were more powers that can be suggested.

Comment: So, if 5D beings share the powers of 4D beings, then just use the powers of 4D beings, other than the X-Ray Vision and looking strange thing I already mentioned.

Comment: ? *We* are quadridimensional beings, existing is the usual quadridimensional spacetime. What do you mean by "superowers of quadridimensional beings"?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer because, beyond some physics jargon, you have not told us what you mean by "5 dimensional creature". You are simultaneously asking us to answer "what is a 5 dimensional creature" and "what powers do they have."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effortless time travel. Moving through a brane as a 3d being limits you to travel along the time dimension in only one direction, but a 5d being experiences no such limitation. They can approach the brane from any direction, and can inject themselves into the brane at arbitrary points that appear to 3d beings as "time travel".

Within a brane, they also have abilities that appear to be violations of the laws of thermodynamics. They aren't creating matter and energy ex nihilo, but it sure looks like that to us.

They are likely invulnerable to beings trapped within branes. They are effectively omniscient as well, any strategy employed against them cannot work because they need only check what you will attempt/accomplish in the future. Worse, they can avoid the consequences of those efforts simply by not manifesting at the point in time where the efforts would come to fruition... they need not take active counter-measures.

Beings trapped within a brane are at most ants in an ant farm to them.

Answer (score 0):

This multidimention universe is not quite 5D, it is more like 3d++ (fist "+" is time, senond "+" is diversity). Diversity isn't even a one dimention. Strictly speaking it is *continuum* of dimentions (i.e. vectors of any basis in diversity are forming a continuous space)

Firstly, this creature *would not* have any sort of "x-ray vision" (which has nothing to do with x-rays). This requires 4th **spatial** dimension. Your 4th dimention is not truly spatial.

Secondly, this universe will constantly expand in "diversity dimention" at high speed. There are enormous amount of quantum processes happen each second and eachof them increases "number of universes" (the analog of length in diversity dimention) by several times. You have to do something with it. Like increasing "diversity size" of creature at the same rate, for example.

Now for superpowers:

Specific to this scenario:

- **Knowlige of all possibilites**. Not all actually, but all in "observable range". For example this creature would clearly see if dice is truly random or it is fake. Because it/he/she would see all there probable outcomes of a throw. And it/she/he would see any irreguarities in the outcome. This also applies to other events like deaths (if one ever wanted to talk to dead people - it is possible if you are 4D). Password bruteforcing would also be much easer fot it/she/him. There are very many possibilites to utilise this "power"
- **Getting any possible object/creature**. If FTL is possible this creature can just walk to universe where it was invented and bring it to any other universe. If lightsabre is possible this creature can just have it. Dinosaurs, sentient octopuses - you name it. Any possibilities, even those wich are almoust impossible (like finding room where all air keeping at the ceiling for thousands of years) are opened for it/he/she.

Common for all 4D scenarios:

- **ability to vanish and appear out nothing**, **bizzare change of a form**. This how treveling of this creature along "diversity axis" would look like for us. If this creature does not like what happening around it just can leave this universe to some more pleasant place.
- **obstacle avoidance** - for this creature it is not like for "simple 4D" creature, but principle is the same. Walk in diversity dimention were this wall is destroyed or wasn't build and than work back - and you have passed behind any wall.

This creature is also would have some super vulnerabilites. For example, being caught in gunfight is a garntee of being hurt. Somewhere somehow bullet would pass throu its body.